# MS-Access auto enter information based on date

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have a query that calculates an employees anniversary date.  I would like that query to generate an entry event for my Table based on the current date.  Basically automatically generate an anniversary vacation accrual when their anniversary date comes.  Here is an example of my table.

```
Table name "SchedulingLog"
LogID "PrimaryKey AutoNbr"
UserID "Employee specific"
LogDate
EventDate
Category "ex Vacation, Anniversary..."
CatDetail "ex. Vacation Day Used, Anniversary..."
Value "ex. -1, 1..."
```

My query

```
Query Name "qry_YOS"
UserID "Employee Specific"
DOH "Employee hire date"
YearsOfService "calculated Field"
Annual "calculated Field"
Schedule "Employee Specific"
Annual Vac Days "calculated field"
Anniversary "calculated Field"
```

Query associated SQL

```
INSERT INTO schedulinglog
            (userid,
             [value],
             eventdate,
             logdate,
             category,
             catdetail)
SELECT roster.userid,
       [annual] * [schedule]                                      AS [Value],
       Month([wm doh]) & "/" & Day([wm doh]) & "/" & Year(DATE()) AS EventDate,
       DATE()                                                     AS LogDate,
       category.[category name]                                   AS Category,
       catdetail.catdetail
FROM   roster,
       tblaccrual,
       category
       INNER JOIN catdetail
               ON category.categoryid = catdetail.categoryid
WHERE  (( ( [tblaccrual] ! [years] ) < Round(( DATE() - [wm doh] ) / 365, 2) ))
GROUP  BY roster.userid,
          roster.[wm doh],
          Round(( DATE() - [wm doh] ) / 365, 2),
          roster.schedule,
          Month([wm doh]) & "/" & Day([wm doh]) & "/" & Year(DATE()),
          DATE(),
          category.[category name],
          catdetail.catdetail
HAVING ( ( ( category.[category name] ) LIKE "vacation*" )
         AND ( ( catdetail.catdetail ) LIKE "anniversary*" ) );
```

I know it is possible I just dont know where to begin.

Comment: You wish to insert the data returned by your query into a table, is that correct? You can base an append query on an existing query.

Comment: Yes to the first question.  And a BIG??? to the second.

Comment: Using the query design window, add your saved query to the grid and choose Append from the toolbar. Select the table to add the results to, you will end up with something like `INSERT INTO Table1 ( AText2, ANumber )
SELECT Query1.AText2, Query1.Total
FROM Query1;`

Comment: I have revised the SQL and query table a bit based on the above feedback. Now i am being asked to "Enter Parameter Value" "Annual"

Comment: That means it cannot find Annual, but you have not posted your revised SQL, so that is all I can say.

Comment: Remou, I have corrected the issue.  I changed a field name trying to match up my query to the table.

Comment: Now the final question...  Do i have to do anything else to trigger the event update into the main table?

Comment: Yes. You need to cause the query to run :) What would suit your application? A date change? A button?

Comment: I could place a button on the opening splash or trigger the append event from the splash screen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21334/discussion-between-remou-and-desert-spider)

Comment: Cant from my work PC.  IF you fill in the answer I will accept and Upvote!.  THanks Remou!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the query design window, add your saved query to the grid and choose Append from the toolbar. Select the table to add the results to, you will end up with something like:

```
 INSERT INTO Table1 ( AText2, ANumber ) 
 SELECT Query1.AText2, Query1.Total 
 FROM Query1;
```

You can trigger the query to run on an event or ask the user to click a button.

Comment: Thanks. You did all the heavy lifting yourself.